# swift: reset screen orientation to portrait

Tags: ios, swift, screen-orientation

I used the following code to rotate a view controller to PortraitUpsideDown:

```
class VC : UIViewController {

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
            return true
                }


    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue)
    }
```

However, on the next view controller I want the screen orientation to be back to Portrait. How do I reset this?

This didn't work:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        return false

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this in your `viewDidAppear`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape{
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

**Update**
To check for PortraitUpSideDown

```
if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue{
     let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
     UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

**Update 2**
Were you want the PortaitupsideDown add this block of code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue != UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue{
            let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue
            UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        }
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown
    }
```

Comment: Just checked my app through TestFlight. It's working, and it's beautiful! Only problem is that the user has to lock autorotate on the iPad, because otherwise it will also use Landscape. I had tried to delete Landscape from Info.plist, but then it wouldn't allow me to build. For now I'm happy with my very first app. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Great @mojomo! Strange that it´s rotating to landscape for you on an iPad... I saw in your project that you only had enabled Portrait and PortaitUpSideDown.

Comment: Yes, I had to re-add it later cause it wouldn't let me build/submit. I will now try a version in which I unchecked Landscape in the deployment Info but I'll leave it there in the Info.plist.